# "Insert Into" syntax error?

Tags: vba, ms-access

**Using Access 07 -"Insert INTO" using SQL:**  In the attached script it inserts data into another table, but only if I remove the `OCC_Scenario`. I need OCC_Scenario and many more values.

The error is a Syntax error but I have tried every combination.  Can anyone see a syntax error?

```
SSql = "Insert INTO tbl_transactions (Caseid,OCC_Scenario,RoleId) Values  ('" & CaseId & "',[OCC_Scenario]" ',
SSql = SSql & "', 'SR');"
DoCmd.RunSQL SSql
```

Comment: It is nearly always better to use `db.Execute` instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL SSql`

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophe and comma at the end of the first line look inappropriate.

Comment: SSql = "Insert INTO tbl_transactions (Caseid,RoleId,OCC_Scenario, Case_Status, Overall_Status) Values  ('" & CaseId & ""
 SSql = SSql & "', 'SR', " & OCC_Scenario & ", " & Case_Status & ", " & Overall_Status & ");"
DoCmd.RunSQL SSql

Comment: Ok, the script will now update 4 values but when I ads the 5th, a pop up says "Enter Parameter Value".  I have inspects the code and it's identical to the previous value just another value. Are there limitations or something I am unaware of????                      SSql = "Insert INTO tbl_transactions (Caseid,RoleId,OCC_Scenario, Case_Status, Overall_Status) Values ('" & CaseId & "" SSql = SSql & "', 'SR', " & OCC_Scenario & ", " & Case_Status & ", " & Overall_Status & ");" DoCmd.RunSQL SSql

Comment: Found it, this works perfect:                                      Dim SSql As String
SSql = "Insert INTO tbl_transactions (Caseid,Roleid,OCC_Scenario, Case_Status, Overall_Status, LoanNbr, Case_Det, Inj1, Sum1) Values  ('" & CaseId & ""
SSql = SSql & "', 'SR', '" & OCC_Scenario & "', '" & Case_Status & "', '" & Overall_Status & "', '" & LoanNbr & "', '" & Case_Det & "', '" & sr_Inj1 & "', '" & sr_Sum1 & "');"
DoCmd.RunSQL SSql